# How to make generic repository for two domains to avoid adding dependencies?

Tags: c#, architecture, repository

I am making an app which has two separate domains, which contain models which represent different concepts:

[image: Architecture diagram]

Now, I want to create generic repository which would allow me to make operations on data sets, and I want it to be used by both DataAccess projects, because DRY. The problem is, I would write these repositories in a way that they would use id of entity, so I need base type or at least interface which will allow me for operating on those. I would create generic repository using `BaseEntity` which contains ID like that:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> where T: BaseEntity
{
   public T SomeActionThatRequiresId(int id)
   {
     // something that requires ID from BaseEntity
   }
}
```

The problem is I don't know where to put `BaseEntity`.

There is always the talk that domain projects should not have dependecies in them, so I don't want to create separate "foundation" project that would be referenced, to keep up with this idea.

Putting it in one of the domain projects and then referencing it in other doesn't even count if I want to keep up with above rule.

I have no idea how to properly do this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion regarding your UML diagram as it uses inheritance instead of dependency relationships. Also, you've mentioned the domain doesn't depend on anything else. In that case, the arrows are in the wrong direction.

Comment: Maybe what you call a separate foundation is more of a utility library?

What about a GenericRepository like that :
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TKey>
{
  public TEntity SomeActionThatRequiresId(TKey id) { }
} ?
Adding a new generic parameter into your GenericRepository is a way to be non dependent of the BaseEntity interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is in two parts...

**Part 1: Where to put BaseEntity**

Put it in a separate independent place.

In this way the domains can all depend on it, without depending in each other.

Below you can see a multi-layered architecture where the usual suspects (UI, logic, data access) are appropriately separated.  Concepts that they need to share are in the `Common` layer, which sits off to the side.  It is referenced by most other projects/assemblies, but it's safe to do so because code in Common is relatively more stable.

E.g. Poco's are dumb data structures and are less likely to change compared to (for example) logic code which uses them.  If a Poco does need to change it's most likely you'd already be wanting to change the other layers also anyway (e.g. driven by a functional change).

Therefore, `Common` (or some similar domain independent place) where you should put your `BaseEntity`.

[image]

**Part 2: Are you solving the right problem?**

The sense I get (echoed by others reading this thread) is that you **might** be focusing on the wrong problem.  If that's the case - that's ok.  It's easily done and you shouldn't beat yourself up about it - or worse, get sucked into a [sunk cost fallacy](https://www.behavioraleconomics.com/resources/mini-encyclopedia-of-be/sunk-cost-fallacy/).

The issue is that as soon as you have one implementation that is used widely (like your generic repo), it becomes constraining.  Use of base classes and inheritance (especially when contrasted with interfaces) is a great example of this general problem.

At an architectural level, reuse can be achieved in a few ways, one is through **patterns**.  In your case all you need to do is identify a pattern (or combination of patterns) that work well for you in addressing your needs and priorities (e.g. code maintainability, ability to meet functional requirements, flexibility - whatever).

Reusing these patterns means you have consistency and clarity, the fact that you might have duplicate code is not a concern on the basis that the benefits of the patterns outweigh any the negatives of duplicate code.

Then there's the **[Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) (SRP)**.  Having a single generic repo breaks SRP because it's trying to work across all domains - each of which will have different design and requirements forces working on them in different ways that will conflict with the generic repo idea.

The generic repo looks like it's doing just one thing (data access) - but that one thing is usually too large and complex.  To say that a generic repo is 'doing SRP' is an illusion.

Having attempted similar paths myself (and observed them on projects), you'll find that there will be data-access **edge cases** where the generic repo idea gets in the way - such as when you have cross-domain activities, especially if runtime performance for those needs to be especially high.

Use of DRY is good, but it's one tool of many, not an end in it's own right, and it's use needs to be balanced with other considerations.

Comment: Well, maybe you're right. I will take a better look at my architecture and check if there are better ways to do it. I find your answer great.

Comment: Thanks Adam.  One other thing - if you're ever unsure what to do, do a proof-of-concept and see how that goes; test it with scenarios you know you'll face so that you can prove it one way or the other - e.g. simple read, complex read, update, and especially complex edge cases if you already know of any.

Answer (score 3):

Not to put to fine a point on it, I think you may be overestimating the importance of DRY as a principal, and trying to define common foundations too soon. A major limitation of DRY is when it causes dependency issues, which you seem to have hit at a very early design stage.

If Config & Core really are separate domains, then it would seem probable that their data access patterns will diverge over time. There is nothing wrong with repeating yourself at least once early on in development, and then waiting to see if they do diverge. You can always consolidate them into a generic repository some time later if they always need to change in sync.

Likewise your statement: "There is always the talk that domain projects should not have dependecies in them" should be treated as a guide and not an hard and fast rule.

If you want all of your domain entities to have common properties, perhaps audit fields in addition to an int id field, then a common base entity library is the obvious solution, and shouldn't be ruled out.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is very important when going into app development. Shame I cannot give two best answers!

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this answer because comment has limited number of characters. :)

From what I understand you are not really looking to find generic way to implement interface. I think there is common misconception about `DRY`. If you create two repositories that are implemented in simmilar manner (having same methods like `GetById`) this is not `DRY`. `DRY` is when you are `copy-pasting` code that is doing exactly the same thing in the same context.

You have two completly different contexts one of them is `Configuration`and second one is `Core`. In that case you would be breaking `Common Closure Principle` because  repositories would be sharing the same interface while they probably have different axis of change.

Based on what you have described I'd like you to confirm that you are using UML correctly (`Core` project is being inherited by `DataAccess` or you wanted to show what is direction of references? so `Core` is being referrenced by `DataAccess`?)

I don't know if that would be best suting to you but `Data Access Layer` should be referencing `Domain Layer`. Since most of the times `Data Access` is only used to presist `Domain` objects or to retrive `Domain` objects and should not be referenced by any other place.

In that case that would look like this:

[image]

Arrows represent what is referencing what. In that case you put `IConfigRepo` into `Config.Domain` project and implementation of that `Repository` is done in `Config.DataAccessLayer` that gives you ensurence that your Domain provides contract and knows how that is allowed to fetch data but doesn't know how they are stored. So you are allowed to store them in SQL or No-SQL database.

Know your `Core` project is simply delegating job to correct `Domain` project. It can be done anyhow but you are sure that `Buisness logic` is stored in specific `Domain` project.

Regarding the idea of having abstract repository to fetch records. What would be benefit of that? Are you sure that you want to allow polymorfic execution in `Core.Domain` of repository that is implemented in `Config.DataAccess`?

Comment: Creating UML I meant to indicate reference - `Core` references `Core.DataAccess` and `Config.DataAccess`, and those reference their domains respectively. In my post I meant that I don't want to write two implementations separately, I want to have repositories share as much code as possible, while having two domains (after all, they will do the same for all entities) - that is why I wanted the same base implementation to be in both projects, still not using entities that would require reference from `Domain`s.

Comment: Also, `Domain` projects are containing mainly entities, so they are lowest level, while you seem to define `DataAccess` as lowest one.

Comment: So the question is what is `Entity` in your case and what is `Core`? Is `Core` acttualy a domain where `buisness rules` are defined and domain is placeholder for database structures?

Comment: As for now, there is no major business logic implemented, but as far as I though about it, `Core` would have this logic implemented, while `DataAccess` defines relations and constrains of the entities, as well as DbContext and such. Entities itself are in `Domain`

Comment: In that case I think you are using (in my opinion) incorrect syntax. Domain is commonaly used for something that contains `Buisness logic` in that case what you call `Domain` is something that stores `Anemic structures` that represent database schema in code. In my opinon you are putting to much attention in creating generic repo  :)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard for us to find the optimal solution without knowing the details of your project.

But I will try to give you some options:

1. Extend your core library with BaseEntity definition. Benefit: That seems to follow your basic design according to the little diagram but also means your repo module will depend on the core library.
2. Introduce new intermediate Layer that defines BaseEntity. If for some reason it doesn't belong into the existing Core library you can create a new library that is common to both domains and derived from Core, with the same dependency problem just on the intermediate library.
3. You don't create BaseEntity and instead the Repo Module provides the necessary interfaces in pure function form, e.g. IRepoObject { getId(); } and your domain objects implement that interface. This has clean separation of concerns. (And it is not a problem that the domain module requires the repo module because they provide repo functionality now)
4. Functional Programming Approach: If the data structures that the repo module needs are not overly complex you just pass those as primitives on the function calls, e.g. doRepoStuff(String id, Byte[] blob, ...). So the repo module would be agnostic to any specific classes or interface implementation.

In my experience simple solutions are usually preferable over complicated object oriented designs with deep inheritance and lots of references, so I would tend to use solution 3 or 4 depending on the complexity of data exchanged.

Comment: Core is higher level of abstraction than the rest classes in this diagram. How can I define Base Entity in core if I need it in `DataAccess` for repo and in domain for entities to inherit it?

Comment: As I mentioned - We don't know the details of your design, but your UML picture means that DataAccess and then Domain are derived from Core, as such a common functionality could be put up on the higher level and the derived levels would both have access. But please read my whole answer - No 1 would not be what I would necessarily recommend.

Comment: I meant it to be the other way around, with Core aggregating all other projects. I have implemented abstract class of generic repository with abstract GetId method, and now every derived implementation requires to override of that method to indicate how to get id from current type. Now Domain don't rely on any external base entity, but I have one-for-all generic repo implementation

Comment: Aggregation is generally expressed an arrow that ends in a rhomb and not  triangle. Below is an example.  So in order to use my proposal 1 or 2 you would have to introduce the superclass in a new commonly used library then.  https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/